# How can I enable "Avg Page Load Time (sec)" and "Avg Page Download Time(sec)" in my Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, cloudflare, load-time

I just read an article on Cloudflare.

https://community.cloudflare.com/t/testing-argo-performance/3304

There is screenshot and two metrics are  "Avg Page Load Time (sec)" and "Avg Page Download Time(sec)".

How can I see that in my GA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second screenshot you have provided comes from Analytics.  You can find it under Behavior>Site Speed>Page Timings.

However, the first screenshot I believe is from the legacy version of Google Search Console.  I don't think the exact screenshot you have show is available anymore (but someone else here may know where to find it).  However, something similar is available in GSC, under Settings and then click "Open Report" to the right of Crawl Stats in the main screen.

You might also find the following Google support doc helpful.  [Where to find the metrics, and what they mean](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2383341?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article)